# Toggle Azure VM creation in Terraform

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I have to provision a Windows VM in `Azure` using `terraform`, only the condition is, VM(along with dependent resources, like VNET, NSG, PublicIP, etc) should be created for all other environments except DEV.

If I run `terraform plan` with below terraform code. I am getting this error.

```
##[error]Terraform command 'plan' failed with exit code '1'.:  Missing resource instance key |  Missing resource instance key |  Missing resource instance key

[0m  on main_infra_app.tf line 284, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "network-interface":
284:         subnet_id                     = "${[4mazurerm_subnet.snet[0m.id}"
[0m
Because azurerm_subnet.snet has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed
on specific instances.
For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
azurerm_subnet.snet[count.index]
```

Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet-main" {
    count               = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                = "$var.name"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = "$var.location"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
} 

#Create Public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "PublicIP" {
    count                        = "${var.env  == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                         = "${var.ip}"
    location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    allocation_method            = "Static"
}

#Create Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
    count                = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                 = "${var.subnet}"
    resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "azurerm_virtual_network.vnet-main"
    address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

#Create Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "NSG" {
    count               = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                = "${var.nsg}"
    location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

  security_rule  {
  ...
    }
  security_rule {
  ...
    }
}

#Create Network Interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "network-interface" {
    count                     = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                      = "${var.nic}"
    location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${var.devops_stage == "dev" ? azurerm_network_security_group.NSG[count.index] : azurerm_network_security_group.NSG.id}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "IP-Conf-1"
        subnet_id                     = "${var.devops_stage == "dev" ? azurerm_subnet.snet[count.index] : azurerm_subnet.snet.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id           = "${var.devops_stage == "dev" ? azurerm_public_ip.PublicIP[count.index] : azurerm_public_ip.PublicIP.id}"
   }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    count               = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                  = var.vm_name
    location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    network_interface_ids = "${var.env == "dev" ? azurerm_network_interface.network-interface[count.index] : azurerm_network_interface.network-interface[count.index]}"
    vm_size               = "Standard_D13_v2"
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from your Terraform code, you want to add the condition that if the variable env is matched with "dev" to judge create the VM and other resources or not. I think you only need to add the condition at the count, not any other places. So finally, the Terraform code should be like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet-main" {
    count               = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                = "${var.name}"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
} 

#Create Public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "PublicIP" {
    count                        = "${var.env  == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                         = "${var.ip}"
    location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    allocation_method            = "Static"
}

#Create Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
    count                = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                 = "${var.subnet}"
    resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet-main[count.index].name}"
    address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

#Create Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "NSG" {
    count               = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                = "${var.nsg}"
    location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

  security_rule  {
  ...
    }
  security_rule {
  ...
    }
}

#Create Network Interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "network-interface" {
    count                     = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                      = "${var.nic}"
    location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.NSG[count.index].id}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "IP-Conf-1"
        subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.snet[count.index].id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id           = "${azurerm_public_ip.PublicIP[count.index].id}"
   }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    count               = "${var.env == "dev" ? 0 : 1}"
    name                  = var.vm_name
    location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    network_interface_ids = "${azurerm_network_interface.network-interface[count.index].id}"
    vm_size               = "Standard_D13_v2"
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles ! I was using conditions at component level too. `NSG[count.index].id` worked perfectly

Comment: @MangeshBiradar That's great!